Mold on floor joists?
We have been living in this house for a little over a year now and recently had to have the entire HVAC replaced. The house is a split level, with the bedrooms being in the basement and living space upstairs.
While the HVAC guys were up there they noticed that a lot of the previous system was installed incorrectly, including the draining system for the HVAC system and it had not been properly draining for years. He also let us know that while they were up there they noticed a lot of the beams were dark and discolored but he was unsure if it was mold or just age (the house was built in 1990).
The bedrooms have always been pretty humid, and upon cleaning out the closest we have noticed some mold growing on clothing in one of the closets. We are so unsure of what to do next or even how to see if it is mold, this is our first home and we are clueless on the homeowner stuff and trying our best to learn as we go.
Does anyone know if this is mold or just age, or what we should do next? We know that we need to get it tested but don’t know how to go about that.



If you have moisture on anything organic and nontoxic, you may have mold. Most molds are mostly harmless except to those of us who have severe allergies; just remove the source of moisture so it stops growing and clean.

Does anyone know if this is mold? ... yes, someone that can test it

Unless you had the subfloor replaced recently, this is just the wood aging. If it was systemic, you would see all surfaces affected.

I don't think there is much to do here and you can easily test it out...
First there is nothing in the pictures that makes me think there is mold.   It certainly looks like the joists have aged and the patina may be due to a little extra moisture.    It is rather odd comment from an HVAC person saying you might have mold or maybe not... usually those guys know for sure.    Also mold is pretty easy to spot and even if you have starved it there should be some heft to it.
If you have even 5% of concern, simply clean a 4' strip.    There are tons of products to get rid of mold on wood and even natural ways (wear mask and gloves). Clean that strip and then wait a couple weeks.   If that strip looks no different, not mold.    If it just looks cleaner but same color... you just have aged/dirty joists.    Your joists are encapsulated by drywall.    Dust and dirt is in the air on drop ceilings and the joists will be a bit dirty.

In the United States, mold is one of the things that can get tested as part of a home inspection.  A home inspection is a pretty standard thing.  You can get a recommendation from any realtor.  In some states, the same inspector will do the mold test and everything else.  In other states, the mold inspection will require a separate specialist.
A possible process in the US would be to call a home inspector and ask if that company can do a mold inspection.  If not, can you get a recommendation for someone who can.
Alternately, you might just Google for "mold inspection near me".  Skip any results that talk about restoration.  Those are the people you call after getting a positive result from mold inspection.  Get the inspection first.  After you remediate or restore, get a second inspection to verify that you were successful at getting rid of the mold.
If you are not in the US, the process may be different.
